# What the sequence of the strings locks in case of SELECT … INNER JOIN … FOR UPDATE and how to avoid deadlock?

Tags: mysql, sql, deadlock, percona

Persona MySQL 5.7.21-20

```
— Memory temporary table TQueue
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TQueue (
    ID bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    QUEUE_STATUS enum ('ADDED', 'PROCESSED', 'SUCCESS', 'ERROR') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'ADDED',
    QUEUE_TIMEOUT datetime NOT NULL,
    ACTION enum ('INSERT', 'DELETE', 'UPDATE') NOT NULL,
    REPORT_ID tinyint(4) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    LOGIN int(11) NOT NULL,
    `GROUP` char(16) NOT NULL,
    ENABLE int(11) NOT NULL,
    ENABLE_CHANGE_PASS int(11) NOT NULL,
    ENABLE_READONLY int(11) NOT NULL,
    ENABLE_OTP int(11) NOT NULL,
    PASSWORD_PHONE char(32) NOT NULL,
    NAME char(128) NOT NULL,
    COUNTRY char(32) NOT NULL,
    CITY char(32) NOT NULL,
    STATE char(32) NOT NULL,
    ZIPCODE char(16) NOT NULL,
    ADDRESS char(128) NOT NULL,
    LEAD_SOURCE char(32) NOT NULL,
    PHONE char(32) NOT NULL,
    EMAIL char(48) NOT NULL,
    COMMENT char(64) NOT NULL,
    ID_DOCUMENT char(32) NOT NULL,
    STATUS char(16) NOT NULL,
    REGDATE datetime NOT NULL,
    LASTDATE datetime NOT NULL,
    LEVERAGE int(11) NOT NULL,
    AGENT_ACCOUNT int(11) NOT NULL,
    TIMESTAMP int(11) NOT NULL,
    BALANCE double NOT NULL,
    PREVMONTHBALANCE double NOT NULL,
    PREVBALANCE double NOT NULL,
    CREDIT double NOT NULL,
    INTERESTRATE double NOT NULL,
    TAXES double NOT NULL,
    SEND_REPORTS int(11) NOT NULL,
    MQID int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    USER_COLOR int(11) NOT NULL,
    EQUITY double NOT NULL,
    MARGIN double NOT NULL,
    MARGIN_LEVEL double NOT NULL,
    MARGIN_FREE double NOT NULL,
    CURRENCY char(16) NOT NULL,
    API_DATA blob DEFAULT NULL,
    MODIFY_TIME datetime NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID),
    INDEX IDX_JOIN USING BTREE (LOGIN, REPORT_ID)
  )
  ENGINE = MEMORY;


CREATE TABLE `MT4_USERS` (
  ID bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    REPORT_ID tinyint(4) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    LOGIN int(11) NOT NULL,
    `GROUP` char(16) NOT NULL,
    ENABLE int(11) NOT NULL,
    ENABLE_CHANGE_PASS int(11) NOT NULL,
    ENABLE_READONLY int(11) NOT NULL,
    ENABLE_OTP int(11) NOT NULL,
    PASSWORD_PHONE char(32) NOT NULL,
    NAME char(128) NOT NULL,
    COUNTRY char(32) NOT NULL,
    CITY char(32) NOT NULL,
    STATE char(32) NOT NULL,
    ZIPCODE char(16) NOT NULL,
    ADDRESS char(128) NOT NULL,
    LEAD_SOURCE char(32) NOT NULL,
    PHONE char(32) NOT NULL,
    EMAIL char(48) NOT NULL,
    COMMENT char(64) NOT NULL,
    ID_DOCUMENT char(32) NOT NULL,
    STATUS char(16) NOT NULL,
    REGDATE datetime NOT NULL,
    LASTDATE datetime NOT NULL,
    LEVERAGE int(11) NOT NULL,
    AGENT_ACCOUNT int(11) NOT NULL,
    TIMESTAMP int(11) NOT NULL,
    BALANCE double NOT NULL,
    PREVMONTHBALANCE double NOT NULL,
    PREVBALANCE double NOT NULL,
    CREDIT double NOT NULL,
    INTERESTRATE double NOT NULL,
    TAXES double NOT NULL,
    SEND_REPORTS int(11) NOT NULL,
    MQID int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    USER_COLOR int(11) NOT NULL,
    EQUITY double NOT NULL,
    MARGIN double NOT NULL,
    MARGIN_LEVEL double NOT NULL,
    MARGIN_FREE double NOT NULL,
    CURRENCY char(16) NOT NULL,
    API_DATA blob DEFAULT NULL,
    MODIFY_TIME datetime NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID),
    UNIQUE KEY IDX_LOGIN_REPORT_ID (`LOGIN`,`REPORT_ID`)
) 
ENGINE=InnoDB 
ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED
```

The data is selected from the queue in memory table TQueue.

I need to do insert into table MT4_USERS. The existing strings should be updated, so I do ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE.

In order to ensure that there is no deadlock happend I try to make exclusive lock before INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE.

```
SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED;
START TRANSACTION;
— hold exclusive lock on MT4_USERS table
SELECT 
u.* 
FROM 
TQueue q 
INNER JOIN MT4_USERS u USING (LOGIN, REPORT_ID) 
FOR UPDATE;

— insert to MT4_USERS form TQueue ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
INSERT MT4_USERS (REPORT_ID, LOGIN, `GROUP`, ENABLE …)
SELECT
    REPORT_ID, LOGIN, `GROUP`, ENABLE, ENABLE_CHANGE_PASS …
FROM TQueue
ORDER BY ID ASC
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    `GROUP` = VALUES(`GROUP`),
    ENABLE = VALUES(ENABLE),
    ENABLE_CHANGE_PASS = VALUES(ENABLE_CHANGE_PASS),
    …
COMMIT;
```

Ideally, I want to make exclusive lock for strings of table MT4_USERS that is consistent with strings of table TQueue with it's fields (LOGIN, REPORT) in order to execute INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE without deadlock.

But I get deadlock in parallel transaction. It does the same actions but with the table MT4_TRADES. It additionally makes LEFT JOIN MT4_USERS.

```
SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED;
START TRANSACTION;
— hold exclusive lock on MT4_TRADES table
SELECT
t.*
FROM
TQueue q
INNER JOIN MT4_TRADES t USING (TICKET, REPORT_ID)
FOR UPDATE;

— insert to MT4_TRADES form TQueue ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
INSERT MT4_TRADES (REPORT_ID, TICKET, LOGIN, SYMBOL, …)
SELECT
q.REPORT_ID, q.TICKET, q.LOGIN, q.SYMBOL, …
FROM
TQueue q
LEFT JOIN MT4_USERS mu USING(REPORT_ID, LOGIN)
ORDER BY
q.ID ASC
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
LOGIN = VALUES(LOGIN)
,SYMBOL = VALUES(SYMBOL)
,DIGITS = VALUES(DIGITS)
,…
COMMIT;

SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS
------------------------
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
------------------------
2018-05-05 00:24:35 0x7fd53e5a6700
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 178168806, ACTIVE 1 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 17 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 45 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 17661615, OS thread handle 140555520485120, query id 4591798647 event_scheduler Sending data
SELECT u.* FROM TQueue q INNER JOIN MT4_USERS u USING (LOGIN, REPORT_ID) FOR UPDATE
*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 876643 page no 46339 n bits 952 index IDX_LOGIN_REPORT_ID of table `Developer`.`MT4_USERS` trx id 178168806 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 178168783, ACTIVE 3 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 6, locked 4
8870 lock struct(s), heap size 1138896, 22372 row lock(s), undo log entries 1876
MySQL thread id 17661574, OS thread handle 140553850873600, query id 4591797640 event_scheduler
INSERT MT4_TRADES
  (
    REPORT_ID, TICKET, LOGIN, SYMBOL, DIGITS, CMD, VOLUME, OPEN_TIME, OPEN_PRICE, SL, TP, CLOSE_TIME,
    EXPIRATION, REASON, CONV_RATE1, CONV_RATE2, COMMISSION, COMMISSION_AGENT, SWAPS, CLOSE_PRICE,
    PROFIT, TAXES, COMMENT, INTERNAL_ID, MARGIN_RATE, `TIMESTAMP`, MAGIC, GW_VOLUME, GW_OPEN_PRICE,
    GW_CLOSE_PRICE, MODIFY_TIME, CURRENCY, DELIMER, RATE, TICKET_STATUS
  )
  SELECT
    q.REPORT_ID, q.TICKET, q.LOGIN, q.SYMBOL, q.DIGITS, q.CMD, q.VOLUME, q.OPEN_TIME, q.OPEN_PRICE, q.SL, q.TP, q.CLOSE_TIME,
    q.EXPIRATION, q.REASON, q.CONV_RATE1, q.CONV_RATE2, q.COMMISSION, q.COMMISSION_AGENT, q.SWAPS, q.CLOSE_PRICE,
    q.PROFIT, q.TAXES, q.COMMENT, q.INTERNAL_ID, q.MARGIN_RATE, q.`TIMESTAMP`, q.MAGIC, q.GW_VOLUME, q.GW_OPEN_PRICE,
    q.GW_CLOSE_PRICE, q.MODIFY_TIME, mu.CURRENCY, mu.DELIMER, IF(mu.CURRENCY = 'USD', 1, SearchOfRate(q.REPORT_ID, mu.CURRENCY, 'USD', q.MODIFY_TIME, -1)), IF(q.`
*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 876643 page no 46339 n bits 952 index IDX_LOGIN_REPORT_ID of table `Developer`.`MT4_USERS` trx id 178168783 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap
*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 876643 page no 46338 n bits 952 index IDX_LOGIN_REPORT_ID of table `Developer`.`MT4_USERS` trx id 178168783 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
*** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (1)
```

What the sequence of the strings locks in case of SELECT … INNER JOIN … FOR UPDATE and how to avoid deadlock?

Answer (score 0):

The deadlock is on an index of your `MT4_USERS` table, as I'm sure you've noticed. That's why the two queries apparently in different parts of your application collide.

This query

```
SELECT u.* 
  FROM TQueue q 
 INNER JOIN MT4_USERS u USING (LOGIN, REPORT_ID) 
   FOR UPDATE;
```

locks your entire `MT4_USERS` table. Why? Can you lock just one row instead? That's the common use case for which `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` is intended.

Or maybe you should skip the `SELECT FOR UPDATE` lock and the transaction, and just do the `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` operation standalone. If two different operations update the same rows, then the one that comes later will determine the final value. Single queries give consistent results.

(*I have guessed a few things because you didn't show both queries involved in the deadlock.*)

Comment: `"This query locks your entire MT4_USERS table. Can you lock just one row instead?»`
I need to take exclusive lock only for strings that exist in TQueue table.
I don't need to block entire table, that's why I do «SELECT ... FOR UPDATE» 
before the «INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE» starts to execute.
Why do you say query «SELECT ... FOR UPDATE» blocks entire table MT4_USERS?

Comment: `«Or maybe you should skip the SELECT FOR UPDATE lock and the transaction, and just do the INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE operation standalone.»` Without exclusive lock both 2 parallel queries «INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE» get deadlock, it's obvious, I already faced with this situation. That's why I want to take exclusive lock with using query «SELECT ... FOR UPDATE» in advance. The TQueue table may contain from 100 to 10000 rows per 1 transaction. That's why I can't use simple "SELECT … FOR UPDATE", I have to use «SELECT…INNER JOIN..FOR UPDATE».